# Why do my HTTP/1.0 GET request returns OK but no body content?

Tags: http, sockets

I'm making a simple http page-requester in C. It uses sockets to send HTTP/1.0 GET requests to hosts, and parses the answer to effectively download the html file.
However, when i send a request like this:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: myRequester/1.0
```

It returns this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 19 Dec 2011 15:28:08 GMT
Content-Length: 54362
Connection: close
```

But no body content.

Yes, I've put CRLF on the end of every line and a blank line at the end.
I use only one socket through one connection. And i also have to stick to HTTP/1.0.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually reading the full response?  Those headers do indicate that the server is sending a body.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. I've checked the answer length through the recv() return and also strlen()ed the buffer afterwards.

Comment: But are you reading to the end? Note that recv does not necessarily read the full response in one call; you should repeat the call until recv reports that the connection has ended.

Comment: You're calling `recv` multiple times, right? BTW: have you tried just telneting in and typing in your requests to see what happens? eg: `telnet stackoverflow.com 80`. (If you have `nc` that's even better than `telnet` for this purpose.)

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. You're both right. I didn't call recv() multiple times. The problem was with my interpretation of socket implementation. Since i can't delete my question, should i answer it myself explaining that so other people don't make the same mistake i did?

Comment: @alexdantas Don't worry about it. Given that asking the question helped you figure out the problem, and may even help others in the future, I'd say that this wasn't a "waste" of a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the server is actually sending a body but you are not reading all of it.  Most networking systems do not necessarily return all of the response in one function call, because they see it useful that what data is available immediately is returned immediately, even if more is expected.

The Unix system call `recv` returns zero when the connection has ended.  You should keep calling it until you get zero or an error.

Comment: Absolutely right. I'm sorry for wasting a question like this.